# Custom 403 Error page is not displayed when wildcard characters are in the url

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, custom-errors

I have been customizing all error pages in my Apache project. Everything seemed to be ok until 403 Forbidden Error appeared. When I send a wildcard character through the URL (such as a blank space or an asterisk), the custom error page is not displayed.

```
http://localhost:8080/*
```

If 403 Error is caused by another reason (for example accessing a forbidden file) this error does not appear and the custom error page is loaded correctly. My ".htaccess" code is:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Anyone having the same problem? How can I solve it? Can I disable the special chars in order to avoid that error? Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I send a wildcard character through the URL (such as a blank space or an asterisk), the custom error page is not displayed.

*Aside:* A "blank space" isn't a *wildcard* character, but if the requested URL-path starts with a *space* (ie. `%20` when URL encoded) then this is indeed an invalid request - see #1 below.

There are two issues here...

1. Apache will trigger a 403 *early* if there are certain invalid characters (eg. `*`, `:`, `"`) in the URL-path. In some respects this is OS dependent. If the character is not permitted in filenames (according to the underlying OS) then a 403 is triggered when the request is mapped to the filesystem.
2. This occurs *before* `.htaccess` is processed. So if you define the `ErrorDocument` *late* in `.htaccess` then your custom error document is not called. However, if you define the `ErrorDocument` *early* in the server config (or VirtualHost) then this *should* get called.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

You don't need to explicitly pass the requested URL to your `index.php` script. In PHP, this is available in the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` superglobal from within the error document.

Note that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal is not necessarily the same as the similarly named `REQUEST_URI` Apache server variable. The PHP variable contains the query string, whereas the Apache variable does not.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has been very useful. It works perfectly on my localhost. But, what can I do if I don't have access to Apache configuration files?

Comment: If you don't have access to the server config then there is nothing you can do I'm afraid.